# Dispersion of light

Tags: visible-light, fourier-transform, signal-processing, dispersion

I've been taking digital signal processing course. It's pretty interesting for me. One thought came to my mind while I've been practicing numerical problem on Fourier transform.

So my question is how can I prove the dispersion of the white light using the inverse Fourier transform?

Suppose I've got the frequency of the individual light waves and I perform inverse Fourier transform, taking the set of the frequency of those waves. I'll get the frequency of white light. But how can I start the notation for those lights as a signal or function?

Comment: If the dispersion relation of the impulse is linear on its band, it is quite easy to show the dispersion analitically via Fourier transform, while if it is not it is very hard to show it.

Comment: Can you refer me to any of such article or mathematical derivation?

Comment: I have some material but it is not in english, however try to search chromatic dispersion of light